# change the value of posts_per_page on mobile screen

Tags: wordpress, posts

I have this code:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'development', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'order' => 'ASC'); 
$loop = new wp_query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

?>
   //html code here
<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

and I want to change the value of posts_per_page to (-1) on mobile screen to get all posts.

I tried to use
`wp_is_mobile`
but I think it returns true when it is a tablet and I don't want that. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_is_mobile` checks `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and cannot distinguish between a phone and a tablet.
There are several options for solving the problem:

1. Use the library https://github.com/serbanghita/mobile-detect

```php
$detect = new \Detection\MobileDetect;
$deviceType = ($detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');
```

2. Receive posts via Ajax (may affect SEO) by checking the device via javascript:

```js
if(window.matchMedia('(min-width:1024px)').matches){
    // desktop
}
if(window.matchMedia('(max-width:1023px) and (min-width:768px)').matches){
    // tablet
}
if(window.matchMedia('(max-width:767px)').matches){
    // mobile
}
```

3. Display the same posts in different blocks (seems the worst option), for example:

```html
<div class="hidden-mobile">
    <!-- posts -->
</div>
<div class="visible-mobile">
    <!-- posts -->
</div>
```

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .visible-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```